# ML for specific classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart

I have a training dataset for classification problem $X \rightarrow y$. Where $X$ is an $n$th dimensional real vector, $y$ is an integer number in $\{0, 1\}$.

I want to solve the next problem: predict as many lines where $y = 1$ as possible with error level no more than $\alpha = 10\%$. In other words, I want to split dataset ($N$ samples) in two sets: 
1) $k$ - samples predicted to be $y = 1$, where $y = 0$ cases less than $k * \alpha$ 
2) $N-k$ samples - I don't care about. I need to maximize $k$ with given $\alpha$ .

I have a lot of experience in classification with ML, but this problem is rather unusual to me.
Please help me how to formalize this problem for ML. Which and how should I use ML algorithm for the problem?
I will be happy to get advice about general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use logistic regression or discriminant analysis you will get some sort of score for the likelihood that Y = 1. So

1. Split your data into training/test (this assumes a relatively large sample)
2. Apply the classification algorithm of your choice on the training data, as long as it gives a score of some sort.
3. Look at $k*\alpha$ on the test data for various scores.
4. Pick the one you like best

Comment: This the first thing I thought. But I hoped there is more effective way, especially for this goal. Thank you.